# Running a perl script, need to output results to VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, perl

I am running multiple perl scripts (about 2-5) within a ASP.net page using VB.net. The scripts are executing just fine. The script is returning the DNS name and other information of the UNIX server to ensure we have it configured correctly.

I need to output the Perl results to VB.net so I can show the results in the main page (and color code depending on success/failure).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
Showing my code

```
        If rdoUnix.Checked Then
            runUnixScript("testScript.pl", UNIXUSERNAME, UNIXPASSWORD)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub runUnixScript(ByVal SCRIPT As String, ByVal UNIXUSERNAME As String, ByVal UNIXPASSWORD As String)
    Dim COMPUTERNAME As String = FQDN.Text
    Dim virtualFolder As String = "~/Scripts"
    Dim physicalFolder As String = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder)
    Dim processCmdFileTransfer As String = "/K C:\pscp.exe -pw " & UNIXPASSWORD & " " & physicalFolder & "\" & SCRIPT & " " & UNIXUSERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & ":" & SCRIPT

    Dim processCmdFileActions As String = "-ssh -pw " & UNIXPASSWORD & " " & UNIXUSERNAME & "@" & COMPUTERNAME & "XX" & SCRIPT
    ' Transfers Script, Makes it executable, Runs Script and then deletes script
    RunProcess("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", processCmdFileTransfer, SCRIPT)
    RunProcess("C:\plink.exe", processCmdFileActions, SCRIPT, " chmod u+x ./")
    RunProcess("C:\plink.exe", processCmdFileActions, SCRIPT, " ./")
    RunProcess("C:\plink.exe", processCmdFileActions, SCRIPT, " rm ./")
End Sub

Public Sub RunProcess(ByVal processPath As String, ByVal startInfo As String, ByVal script As String, Optional ByVal command As String = "")
    Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(processPath)

    If (InStr(startInfo, "XX") > 0) And (command <> "") Then
        startInfo = startInfo.Replace("XX", command)
    End If

    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = startInfo
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()
    Proc.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting the  [output of the executed code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/b35d40fa-5442-4c97-b718-58861a5f52d6/) using output redirection.

Just pass the perl executable the path of the perlscript in the following line

```
 Dim psI As New ProcessStartInfo("PERL_INSTALLED\\perl.exe SCRIPT_DIR\\MyScript.pl");
```

Comment: I edited the original question to add my code. I am connecting remotely to a unix system and running the script.